# Including Javascript Library to Wicket Panel

Tags: java, javascript, d3.js, wicket

I have two script files lib_network.js and network.js. I have a draw() function in the network .js which calls another function in lib_network.js. Both files uses d3.js functions do certain task.

I am adding both the files in the following way to wicket panel

```
public static final JavaScriptResourceReference NETWORK_JS = new JavaScriptResourceReference(
            SenseAlign.class, "network.js");

    public static final JavaScriptResourceReference NETWORK_CSS = new JavaScriptResourceReference(
            SenseAlign.class, "network.css");

    public NetworkPanel(String id){ 
        super(id);

    }

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse aResponse){
        super.renderHead(aResponse);

        aResponse.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(D3Reference.D3_JS));
        aResponse.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(JqueryReference.jQuery_JS));
        aResponse.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(NetworkLibrary.LIB_NETWORK_JS));
        aResponse.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(NETWORK_JS));
        aResponse.render(JavaScriptReferenceHeaderItem.forReference(NETWORK_CSS));

        String[] annotatorScript = new String[] { 
                "draw(\"" + getMarkupId() + "\")"};

        aResponse.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript(StringUtils.join(annotatorScript, "\n")));
    }
```

I am getting an error when I try to call the function in lib_network.js as

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Also the css file is not loaded properly. Getting a syntax error but the syntax is correct as I have added only two classes in the file.

Could any one tell me the correct way to include the resources.

I have tried looking for the answer in cwiki and wicket guide. They say the above mentioned way but it still does not work for me.

Comment: whoever downvoted it, could you please tell me the reason

Comment: Upvoted as this is a good question

Answer (score 0):

```
new JavaScriptResourceReference(SenseAlign.class, "network.css")
```

You should not use a JavaScriptResourceReference for a CSS file, or it will be compressed with a Javascript compressor. Use a CssResourceReference instead.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to CSS resource and it is working fine. But I still not able to call the function.